# AngularJS - Accessing ng-init variables from run method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init, angularjs-rootscope, angularjs-lifecycle

1) I have variables initialized in ng-init
Eg -

```
ng-init="password='Mightybear'";
```

2) I want to access it from the .run method.
Eg -

```
anguar.module("ngApp", [])
.run(function() {
//Access password here
});
```

Below scenarios I have tried, and did not work -

```
1) angular.module("ngApp", [])
.run(function($rootScope) { 
console.log($rootScope.password) //undefined!!!
});

2) angular.module("ngApp", [])
.run(function($rootScope, $timeout) { 
$(timeout(function() {
console.log($rootScope.password) //undefined!!!
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get ng-init value inside your `run` block

Angular LifeCycle

1. Config Phase (app.config) ($rootScope will not available here)
2. Run Phase (app.run) ($rootScope will available here)
3. Directive Gets Compile()
4. Then controller, directive link function, filter, etc gets executed.(`ng-init` is here)

If you want to get initialize value in run phase then you need to set that value in config phase.

If You want to set the value in config then you can take use of `app.constant`/`provider` which available in configuration phase, don't use `$rootScope` that is considered as bad pattern in AngularJS.

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.constant('settings', {
    title: 'My Title'
})

app.config(function(settings) {
    setting.title = 'Changed My Title';
    //here can you do other configurarion setting like route & init some variable
})

app.run(function(settings) {
    console.log(settings.title);
})
```

Comment: Is app.contant an alternative to global variables? or is it global variables for the angular app?

Comment: app.constant is not global variable thing..you can consider it as one sort of factory..which can contains a static data..

Comment: I need to use it from ng-init and .run only. any ideas? Can i add watch on rootscope?

Comment: why you don't use constant..tell me scenario what you want to do..I'll guide you

Comment: I am writing my ng-init in a jsp. I am dynamically getting username/password in jsp which i want to add in ng-init. And these needsd to be accessed from the .run method.

Comment: are you using `ngRoute` module?

Comment: then you could do like this http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx or you need to call ajax from your config by making your own provider

Answer (score 0):

I'll let you a walkthrough, of how angular loads

angular module ---> .config ----> .run ----> controllers(ng-init)

now you can clear your approach.

Comment: Am new to Angular. My guess is to use $watch. $rootScope.$watch?